# How to address void elements overwhelming analysis?

Tags: r, missing-data, traminer, sequence-analysis

I'm conducting some analysis on sequence data with very different lengths using `TraMineR`. What ends up happening is that the void elements (`%`) used to make the sequences equally long end up overwhelming everything else:

```
seqstatf(cluster1_data)

             Freq      Percent
%          377623 98.366219930
assigned       16  0.004167806
closed       1115  0.290444002
discussed    2454  0.639237291
mentioned     954  0.248505451
merged        421  0.109665403
opened        534  0.139100535
referenced    565  0.147175660
reopened       22  0.005730734
reviewed      191  0.049753188
```

How can I avoid this effect?

Comment: I guess cluster_data is a state sequence object. With which options did you create it? Is the `%` in your original data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The void (`%`) signs came from `NA`s in my original data.

The problem was that I used `seqdef` twice (first on the raw data, and then on the resulting sequence object). Somehow this negated my use of the `missing=TRUE` and `right="DEL"` flags.

Here's how I set the `seqdef` function to discount missing data during the analysis:

```
seqdef(data, right = "DEL")
```